# Problema al llenar input con datos de un select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando de llenar un `input` según un dato que escoja de un `select`, lo hago mediante `AJAX` y `PHP`. Este es mi código:

```
<select id="pro" name="plan" class="form-control">
 <option readonly>Elegir Plan</option>
    <?php
     $result = $obj->ListaPlanes();
     foreach($result as $values){ ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $values['id_plan']?>">
         <?php echo $values['planes'] ?>
       </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="price" value="" readonly>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
 $('#pro').on('change',function(){
  var id = $("#pro").val()
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'ver_price.php',
    data:{'id':id}
 })
  .done(function(listas_cur){
    $("#price").val(listas_cur)
  })
  .fail(function(){
    alert('error')
  })
 });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

  function ver_precio(){
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vmenu.us;charset=utf8','root','');
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM plans WHERE id_plan ='$id'");
    $query->execute();
    $row = $query->fetch();
    $list = $row['price'];
    return $list;
  }
  echo ver_precio();
?>
```

Esos son mis 3 archivos. El resultado que obtengo es absolutamente nada. No me muestra nada en el `input`, ni me da ningún error en console, no obtengo nada.

Comment: Buen código al usar PDO como conexión a datos. Me tomaré la libertad de corregir la sentencia para evitar inyección SQL, como referencia a futuros visitantes que deseen copiar y pegar el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás asignando erróneamente los escuchadores a los eventos, tanto en el `ready` como para el `change`

La documentación de [on(evento,elemento,function())](http://api.jquery.com/on/) nos explicar claramente que el primer parámetro es el **evento** y el segundo es el **elemento** al que desea escuchar *(este último hace falta en su código)* . entonces debería ser.

```
$(document).on('change','#pro',function(){ ...}
```

Y el `ready` del `document` podría ser.

```
$(function() {

});
```

**Completo**

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('change','#pro',function(){
         /**codigo ajax*/
     });
});
```

Comment: Lo he cambiado Joel, pero sigo igual, no obtengo nada. nisiquiera un alert. Nada!

Comment: @AlejoMendoza obtiene algún error en consola? ¿es correcta la ruta del archivo php? . ¿Está seguro que coloco tal cuál está mi código?

Comment: En console no obtengo ningun error. La ruta del archivo PHP la he revisado muchas veces y es la correcta. Incluso he intentado colocando el ajax en un script en mi archivo de la vista, y nada. Y si, he puesto el codigo tal cual me has dicho en la respuesta.

Comment: Ya he arreglado el error Joel, tenia un error que no habia visto en los id. Gracias por la respuesta